# Confusion regarding field and flux

Tags: electromagnetism

Are magnetic field and magnetic flux the same? I am confused because texts books are using these two terms interchangeably.

Answer (score 0):

The magnetic field $\vec B$ is a field of electromagnetic energy usually depicted by lines of force corresponding to this field that transfer the strength of a magnet.

The magnetic flux is a measure of these lines of force that travel through a certain area. That is

$$\Phi = \vec B . \vec A$$

where $\Phi$ is the magnetic flux and $A$ is the area.

From this we can see that $\vec B$ can also be referred to as magnetic flux density.

Answer (score 0):

Of course, They are two different things. First, let's take a look at the definition of the two:

A [magnetic field](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_field) is a picture that we use as a tool to describe how the magnetic force is distributed in the space around and within something magnetic. The magnetic field is described mathematically as a vector field. This vector field can be plotted directly as a set of many vectors drawn on a grid. Each vector points in the direction that a compass would point and has length dependent on the strength of the magnetic force.

---

[Magnetic flux](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Magnetic_flux) is a measurement of the total magnetic field which passes through a given area. It is a useful tool for helping describe the effects of the magnetic force on something occupying a given area. The measurement of magnetic flux is tied to the particular area chosen. We can choose to make the area any size we want and orient it in any way relative to the magnetic field.

If we use the field-line picture of a magnetic field then every field line passing through the given area contributes some magnetic flux. The angle at which the field line intersects the area is also important. A field line passing through at a glancing angle will only contribute a small component of the field to the magnetic flux. When calculating the magnetic flux we include only the component of the magnetic field vector which is normal to our test area.

If we choose a simple flat surface with area $A$ as our test area and there is an angle $\theta$ between the normal to the surface and a magnetic field vector (magnitude $B$) then the magnetic flux is,
$$\Phi=BA\cos\theta$$